# Mongoose saves invalid data without throwing validation errors if model.validate() is called first

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

MongoDB 4.2.2 and Mongoose 5.8.3 (latest) and NodeJS 13.3.0 (Windows x64)

If I create a schema and model, then create an instance of the model and add some data, then run `validate()`, then `save()`: even if `validate()` fails, the data is saved into the collection, without throwing an additional validation error.

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Here's the test code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.connect("mongodb://user:pass@localhost/mydb")
db = mongoose.connection

var Schema = mongoose.Schema


var PartSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        validate: {
            validator: (v) => v !== 'asdf'  // Don't allow name to be 'asdf'
        }
    },
    number: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        validate: {
            validator: (v) => !v.includes(' ')  // Don't allow spaces in part number.
        }
    }
})

var ProductSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    parts: [PartSchema]
})

var Part = mongoose.model('Part', PartSchema)
var Product = mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema)

var p1 = new Product({name:"Baseball Bat", parts:[ new Part({name:"First part", number: "003344"}), new Part({name: "Second part", number: "554422"}) ]})

p1.parts.push(new Part({name: "No number, so invalid"}))  // this one is invalid because no part number is specified (required)
p1.parts.push(new Part({name: 'asdf', number: 'zzzzzaaaa'}))  
p1.parts.push(new Part({name: 'bbbb', number: 'with a space'})) // This one is invalid because number has spaces.
p1.validate()
    .then(() => {console.log('Validation successful')})
    .catch((err) => { console.log("Validation failed.")})
p1.save()
    .then(()=>{ console.log("Saved successfully")})
    .catch((err)=>{console.log("Save ERROR", err)})
```

Running this code yields the following:

```
Validation failed.
Saved successfully
```

And the new document appears in the database:
[image]

However, if I remove the `p1.validate()` before calling `save()`, the save function's `catch()` block triggers and the item is not saved:

```
Save ERROR Error [ValidationError]: Product validation failed: parts.2.number: Path `number` is required., parts.3.name: Validator failed for path `name` with value `asdf`, parts.4.number: Validator failed for path `number` with value `with a space`
    at ValidationError.inspect 
... snipped
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to use `p1.save()` inside the promise chain.

```
p1.validate()
  .then(res => {
    console.log("Validation successful");
  })
  .then(() => {
    return p1.save();
  })
  .then(res => {
    console.log("saved success ", res);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log("Some error.", err);
  });
```

Comment: I could do that, but the point was that this seems a bug: if I call `validate`, it should not interfere with `save` also doing its own validation, whether or not they are called in the same promise chain.  I might want to call `validate`, then do something else based on whether the values were valid.  `save` should always re-validate, no matter whether I just validated or not.

Comment: @RyanGriggs  yes, I agree with that, this is a bug in mongoose library.